# system cannot find the specified file python subprocess

Tags: python

I am trying to run a simple command in python:

```
from subprocess import *    
check_output("ls")
```

When I run this it raises

```
Error:
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Give the full path to the check_output and don't rely on the default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls` doesn’t exist on Windows; `dir` does.  Furthermore, you may need to pass `shell=True`, since it’s built in to `cmd.exe`.

If it’s not a test and you just want to get the contents of a directory, use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) instead.

Comment: hi, but how come the example showed in web always use "ls" as example? that mean I need to run the python in UNIX? why need to put the shell=True?

Comment: @user37970: They probably used it because if it is a UNIX system, it’s going to be there. I’m not sure what else they’d have used that would be a whole lot more platform-independent except perhaps `echo`, but that’s even more likely to be a shell built-in. It needs `shell=True` because there’s no `dir.exe` (as far as I know); the functionality is built into `cmd.exe`, the shell.

Comment: get it!!thanks,u clear all my cloud,um,have another question,do you know how to link html files with python file? or python file with perl files?

Comment: @user37970: I’m not entirely sure what you’re asking. If you want to make some Python code that generates HTML web-accessible, you could use a CGI script. If you want to call a Perl script from Python, you could use the `subprocess` module as you were testing here. If you can express your problem more clearly, you can ask another question.

Comment: @ocktoofay, sorry for the vague statement,I am newbie to python, let say, I have a perl scipt on UNIX: trial.pl print ("hello" world");

and python is on window:
Python SCipt:
subprocess.call("perl trial.pl",shell=True)

it print "1"

Comment: @user37970: As I said, if you can distill your problem but explain it fully and completely, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). It is out of scope for these comments.